# Can I store string in object array by using this string as index?

Tags: java, arrays

Can Java use a String as an index array key?

Example:

```
array["ab"] = "ab";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you cannot. [`Array`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) index must be `integer`.

And if you want to pair them up, look at [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html), where you can use String as a key and value [`Map<String,String>.`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("ab","ab"); //adding key-value;

String value map.get("ab"); //gives you "ab"
```